# Problema de N+1 com @OneToMany

Tags: jpa, jpql

Segue o diagrama de classe para exemplificar o problema:

[Associação entre *User* e *Education*, @OneToMany](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYhIb.png)

Para resolver o problema do N+1 eu utilizo o *JOIN* *FETCH* (*JPQL*). Para os *Users* que possuem *Educations* funciona perfeitamente, o *JPA* faz apenas uma consulta no banco de dados, quando eu faço o *getEducations()* ele não retorna ao banco para procurar pelas *Educations*, a mesma já está na memória, porem quando algum *User* não possui *Educations* o *JPA* retorna para pesquisar no banco de dados pois não encontrou na memória, mesmo acrescentando *fetch* = *FetchType*.*LAZY*.
Eu gostaria que quando algum usuário não possuísse *Education* o *JPA* também não retornasse ao banco de dados para realizar outra consulta.

Segue uma parte do código:

Service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<UserDTO> findAllPaged(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<User> page = repository.findAll(pageable);
        repository.findFullUserProfile(page.getContent());
        return page.map(x -> new UserDTO(x, x.getEducations()));        
    }       
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    
    @Query("SELECT obj FROM User obj "
            + "JOIN FETCH obj.educations "
            + "WHERE obj IN :users ")   
    List<User> findFullUserProfile(List<User> users);
}
```

Entity User:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Education> educations = new HashSet<>();
```

Entity Education:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

Comment: Acho que tu estás confundindo lazy loading com cache. O comportamento esperado de uma prop com `FetchType.LAZY` é isso mesmo, ao executar um `getEducations()`, o JPA irá bater no banco, ao invés de consultar "tudo de uma vez" ao buscar o `User`

Comment: Quando eu busco apenas pelos _Users_ o _JPA_ vai no banco de dados apenas uma vez, então entendo que esta no modo _FetchType.LAZY_. Quando executo o _getEducarions()_ e todos os _Users_ possuem pelo menos 1 _Education_ o _JPA_ vai apenas mais uma vez no banco de dados e trás todos os _Educations_ de todos _Users_; o problema é quando algum dos _Users_ não possui _Education_, o _JPA_ volta no banco de dados para tentar encontra-lo, mas não vai estar lá porque se o _JPA_ não trouxe quando buscou da primeira vez é porque o _User_ não possui nenhuma _Education_, é uma busca desnecessária.